# Firebase data fan out compared to identical updates across multiple paths

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm trying to better understand how Firebase's data fan out can be beneficial.

To aid my investigation, I pose a question: Is the data fan out methodology necessary. See below example taken from the documentation:

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {
    // Create new post at /user-posts/$userid/$postid and at
    // /posts/$postid simultaneously
    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);
    Map<String, Object> postValues = post.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("/posts/" + key, postValues);
    childUpdates.put("/user-posts/" + userId + "/" + key, postValues);

    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

Could I not have achieved the same using this:

```
private void writeNewPost(String userId, String username, String title, String body) {

    String key = mDatabase.child("posts").push().getKey();
    Post post = new Post(userId, username, title, body);

    mDatabase.child(posts).child(key).setValue(post);
    mDatabase.child(user-posts).child(userId).child(key).setValue(post);

}
```

The aim of me asking it in this way is to tease out potential benefits that are perhaps not explicitly conveyed in the docs.
I am specifically looking to keep duplicate data entries in sync. However, again, I could use a similar approach, namely performing identical child updates on two independently defined paths.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  It looks like all you've done is convert a single multi-path update into two separate updates.  That's still technically a fan out, except it no longer happens atomically.  Also, there is no method addChild() on DatabaseReference, so I don't really know what the final result of the second code sample is supposed to do.  Did you mean setValue() instead?

Comment: @DougStevenson, yes, apologies, I meant setValue (corrected). From your comment, and as mentioned in the docs, it seems like the atomic aspect of the update is the main selling point? I can see how that is quite important.

Comment: Yes, you'd want to try very hard to preserve consistency of the database. Also, it's always better to have fewer individual write operations.

Comment: @DougStevenson, thanks for clarifying. It may seem like a trivial question, but the advice of aiming for fewer individual write operations is already more reason for this approach, which was not covered in the docs. Much appreciated.